# Customlistview with checkbox- while scrolling check state is interchanged

Tags: android

I use customize listview with checkbox.while scrolling the  listview the checked state is interchanged how to control interchanged and set it default ie checked items i selected

code for your reference

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView=lInflater.inflate(R.layout.subtag, null);
            holder=new viewHolder();
            holder.check=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtag_checkCatagory);
            holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                        System.out.println("checked item:"+buttonView.getText());
                        temp.add(buttonView.getText().toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp.remove(buttonView.getText().toString());

                    }
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {   
            holder = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.check.setText(list.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: At last i found answer to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last I found answer to above question. In this code check value and `TextView` value is not changing while we scroll the `ListView`

### Steps

1. Instead of `BaseAdapter` use `ArrayAdapter` for *customlistview*
2. Write a bojo class for checkbox selected/unselected and textview get/set
3. Concentrate on `getview()` as I prescribed below

**Code**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.subtag, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subtag_textCatagory);
        viewHolder.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.subtag_checkCatagory);

        viewHolder.text.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                        TagBojo element = (TagBojo) viewHolder.check.getTag();
                        element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        System.out.println(element.getListName());
                });
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.check.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).check.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getListName());
    holder.check.setChecked(list.get(position).getSelected());
    return view;
}
```