# listview with checkbox status changed when scoll

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting an issue while checking the dynamically generated checkbox through list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list)

I have listview with checkboxes.Bydefault all checkboxes are checked.After that some checkboxes unchecked and sroll those checkboxes are checked automatically.But i want after scroll the listview those checkboxes are checked.
My code is:

```
public class  FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    DrunkMessages friendsList;
    boolean[] checkBoxState;

    public FriendListAdapter(DrunkMessages friendsList) {
        this.friendsList = friendsList;
        if (Utility.model == null) {
            Utility.model = new FriendsGetProfilePics();
        }
        Utility.model.setListener(this);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(friendsList.getBaseContext());

        checkBoxState=new boolean[jsonArray.length()];
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return jsonArray.length();
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View hView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.friendslist, null);

            ImageView profile_pic = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            TextView name = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.name);

            final CheckBox checkbox=(CheckBox)hView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        profile_pic.setImageBitmap(Utility.model.getImage(friendid[position], pictures[position]));
        name.setText(names[position]);

        checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                checkBoxState[position]=true;
                status[position]="1";

             Log.e("checked","checked");
            Log.e("Checked",status[position]);
                }
                else{
                 checkBoxState[position]=false;
                status[position]="0";

                Log.e("checked","unchecked");
             Log.e("Checked",status[position]);

                }
               }
               });

      return hView;
}
```

Comment: instead of inflating another xml for checkbox you can take a listview with simple_list_item_multiple_choice attribute.
like this
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,objectOfList);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538867/customlistview-with-checkbox-while-scrolling-check-state-is-interchanged),[Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100518/checkbox-auto-call-oncheckedchange-when-listview-scroll)

Comment: http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convertview may give you previously generated view so dont rely on it. just store your checkbox state's in one boolean array & change that accordingly depends on checkchangelistener callback here is code for you I just modified getView method of your code everything else keep as is

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View hView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.friendslist, null);

                ImageView profile_pic = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
                TextView name = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.name);

                final CheckBox checkbox=(CheckBox)hView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

                checkbox.setTag(new Integer(position));  
            profile_pic.setImageBitmap(Utility.model.getImage(friendid[position], pictures[position]));
            name.setText(names[position]);

            checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            if(checkBoxState[position])
              checkbox.setChecked(true);
            else  
              checkbox.setChecked(false);

            checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    Integer pos = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();     
                    if(isChecked){

                    checkBoxState[pos.intValue()]=true;
                    }
                    else{
                     checkBoxState[pos.intValue()]=false;
                    Log.e("checked","unchecked");

                    }
                   }
                   });

          return hView;
    }
```

Comment: updated my answer please check now

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception at line: checkBoxState[pos.intValue()]=true;

Comment: check my updated answer you have to set tag of checkbox like this checkbox.setTag(new Integer(position));

Comment: k working fine.but I want all checkboxes are checked bydefault.In my xml also checked="true". but why i am getting all checkboxes  unchecked bydefault.please answer me

Comment: your array is not initialized so initialize your checkBoxState array like this Arrays.fill(checkBoxState, true);

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your getview method

```
if(checkBoxState.length>0)
checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
```

Comment: I would suggest simple checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);

Comment: and also getting the same problem

Comment: just see the value checkBoxState[position] through log cat

Comment: I am getting false and also bydefault getting unchecked.But in my xml I wrote android:checked="true".Why i am getting false value

Comment: please give me answer:I want bydefault all are checked

Comment: checkBoxState[position] value is empty by default because it will fill with o or 1 when you perform onclick event

Comment: But i will give one solution save true values to checkBoxState array by default when you are intializing

Comment: But i want my listview view also checked by default

Answer (score 0):

instead of inflating another xml for checkbox you can take a listview with simple_list_item_multiple_choice attribute. like this

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,obje‌​ctOfList);
```

Comment: I used custom listview.How can it is possible?