# CheckBox gets unchecked on scroll in a custom listview, didn't find a solution

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I know this question has a lot of answers in the forum, but I tried all answers and none of them works with my code. The checkbox is unchecked whenever the list is scrolled down. Here is my code:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
boolean[] checkBoxState;
ViewHolder holder;

public ContactsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.listitemlayout, R.id.itemTextView, list);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    checkBoxState = new boolean [list.size()];
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitemlayout, null);
        holder.itemTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } 
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }

    User user = getItem(position);
    holder.itemTextView.setText(user.getName());

    holder.checkbox.setTag(user);
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
                checkBoxState[position]=true;
            else
                checkBoxState[position]=false;
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemTextView;
    CheckBox checkbox;
}
```

}

Please anyone can help me?

Comment: follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538867/customlistview-with-checkbox-while-scrolling-check-state-is-interchanged

Comment: Anand, thank you for your help but that code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired using an [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29) instead of an `OnClickListener`? You can then just assign whatever value you get from `isChecked` into your `checkBoxState` array.

Comment: Then you need more information about what is going on. Try running the debugger and put break points both when you read the value from the array and when you change it to reflect the new checked state.